# Issue with C double pointer allocation

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I read tons of tutos and snippets, but I still don't understand why I get a segfault with this:

```
int fun(char **p) {

  int i;

  *p = malloc(2);
  *p[0]=10;
  *p[1]=20; // segfault NULL pointer

  printf("fun()/n");
  for (i=0; i<2; i++)
   printf("%d ",*p[i]);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  char* buffer;
  int i;

  fun(&buffer);

  printf("main()\n");

  for (i=0; i<2; i++)
   printf("%d ",buffer[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

In gdb, it gives:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x0000000100000dea in fun (p=0x7fff5fbffab0) at test.c:10
10    *p[1]=20;
(gdb) p *p[0]
$1 = 10 '\n'
(gdb) p *p[1]
Cannot access memory at address 0x0
(gdb)
```

I have seen a lot of similar snippets, but there is surely something I am deeply misunderstanding.

Comment: I feel strangely guarded when someone learns from "tons of tutos and snippets"...

Comment: You should check your `malloc` call for errors.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Very interesting. Who are you and do you happen to know?

Comment: @phocean: Well, for starters I've seen a good share of "tutos and snippets" in the wild, and similar questions; and moreover I know a bit about the complexity of C++ and wonder if one can tackle it if spelling out "tutorial" is taxing the attention span already... :-) (But do have a look at our recommended book list!)

Comment: @KerrekSB This is a C question, not that C is a good language either to learn from disparate bits of Internet resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean `(*p)[1]`. What you said is `*(p[1])`.

Comment: That was it. But sad to read your other comment. You didn't respect me without knowing. And where is the crime to begin in C, not understanding something and ask a question? I spent days on a shitty syntax issue. So what? Thanks anyway.

Comment: @phocean: Hey, no offense, and best of luck! Spend some time on SO if you like, I'm sure it'll be a rewarding experience. You'll be answering questions yourself in no time.

Answer (score 0):

try returning the address of the same data type of the variable at the LHS.
malloc() by default returns a void value.
*p = (char*) malloc(2);
this way compiler knows how many bytes it has to move the pointer to fetch new variable.

Comment: This question was answered and accepted a long time ago. Why add another?

Comment: This answer would need to be fixed before it could be terrible and unhelpful. The function `malloc()` does not return `void` and casting to `char` the result of `malloc()` is awful. You may have meant `void*` and `char*`, and then it is still a bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/139746 . And even then this does not answer the question.